# CiviContributions > New Contribution Page with an ANONYMOUS USER and no Login Display in Drupal (CiviCRM 5.25.0 / Drupal 7.70)

Tags: civicontribute

This is a multipart question:

**1.** I have added the following permissions for the anon user:

-CiviCRM: profile listings and forms

and

-CiviCRM: access all custom data

My desire is to block any other access to CiviCRM - I just want individuals to access the page and make a donation. Am I missing any security implication?

---

**2.** I have set up a profile to collect First / Last and Email address, but Drupal is still adding a login - this would be confusing to my users and I would like that not to appear, but not sure how to turn off that from displaying:
[image: Login for Contribution Page]

Answer (score 1):

I think 1 will take care of #2

Profile listings and forms are NOT for your public users. Only trusted users. You want to change that one

Here are the permission you need for Anonymous and Authenticed Users

CiviCRM: profile create

CiviCRM: profile edit

CiviCRM: profile view

CiviContribute: make online contributions

[image]

Comment: That works much the same as my original setting and I am still getting the User name and Password field. Is there no way to turn that off?  As a side note, I just turned on the permissions listed above for the Anon user only

Comment: Yes, you can turn off that login. We just need to find where you have permission set to require login for the form.  When you tested last time, where you still logged in as an admin? If so, then you will see that login unless you also allow Authenticed users on the 4 items I listed.

Comment: I used another browser that was not logged into CiviCRM when I was testing.  So I do have to turn on the options for Auth users (using the same options as with Anon users)? Also, you mentioned a setting for the UN and PW - which one would that be?

Comment: I added a photo to my answer. The circled part is what you said you gave permission on, I am saying you need to remove those permissions. They clearly say they are not for the public access.

Comment: Then the rest of my photo shows what I have checked for permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Got to Structure -> Blocks

Find the User Login block and and disable it or control its visibility by specifying Pages you want it to show up on.

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks for your help and input!

Comment: Glad I could be helpful - Remember to accept the answer so that others now it’s answered.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved via the setting for Anon user noted by Iowa boy and the User Login Block noted by Karin.  I did not add the options in permissions for Auth Users - did not make any difference to operations.

Comment: You probably will want to add the permissions for Auth users. Sometimes returning donors like to see what they have done in the past. If they are signed in, they will not be able to make a new contribution without logging out first.